# Javascript type-mismatch detection

Tags: javascript, dynamic, types

I was wondering how do type mismatches get detected in a dynamic programming language like Javascript? Like if I do something like divide an integer by a string, how does that action get detected?

Comment: Don't really understand this question, for arithmetic operation it's going to coerce the value to a number in the javascript engine, if it doesn't work the value will be `NaN` and so will the result. You're asking how the internal JS engine of a browser handles this?

Comment: [12.6 Multiplicative Operators](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators) -> [12.6.3 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

Comment: If you divide a number by a string, then the JS engine would, by definition, know that. It has to perform the division, after all. It will check the type of the left and right operands and if different, try coerce them to the same base type.